# Перенаправления PHP и .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, .htaccess, redirect

Есть ссылка вида
/pages/users?id=12345 .
Как сделать такую ссылку
/user12345 .

Я так понимаю что это .htaccess .
Но ещё такой вот вопрос в WordPress видно что перенаправления работают и без правил .htaccess ?
Как это работает и можно ли сделать также.

В дополнение прошу может кто знает хорошую документацию по синтаксису .htaccess, а не набор "примеров" использования, желательно русскоязычную.

Comment: http://www.htaccess.net.ru/ но с ВП надо больше работы.

Answer (score 0):

я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на плагины вида 301 редирект
они позволяют настраивать и проверять правила довольно легко и практически не зная синтаксиса .htaccess